# PL/SQL: Given a list of values, return if rows exist for each of them

Tags: sql, oracle, count, left-join

My original sql is,

```
select club_id
     ,  count(club_id) as num_of_players 
  from player 
 where club_id in (1,2,3,4) 
 group 
    by club_id
```

```
    
    
        club_id  num_of_players
        1        5
        2        0
        3        7
        4        0
```

Now I don't really need the count(*) any more.  I just need to know if there is at least one record for a club.  The result I want is,

```
    
    
        club_id  having_record
        1        1
        2        0
        3        1
        4        0
```

How to write such a SQL without using count(*) ?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @jianChen .  . . It is impossible for your query to return `0` counts, so I am a bit lost on what you are really doing.

Comment: "count" may cause a full-table scan or full-index scan.  I think it may make things faster if it stops right away after one record is found for a single value  @Strawberry

Answer (score 2):

As a starter, I would be suprised that your query produces the result that you are showing. You need to generate one row per club in the list, even those that are not in the table to start with: for this, you can use  `union all` in a subquery.

Then, all that is left to do is to bring the table with a `left join`, and finally aggregate; to generate the flags, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select c.club_id, case when count(p.club_id) > 0 then 1 else 0 end player_exists
from (
    select 1 club_id
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
) c
left join player p on p.club_id = c.club_id
group by c.club_id
```

You could also use an `exists` subquery instead of aggregation:

```
select c.club_id,
    case when exists (select 1 from player p where p.club_id = c.club_id)
        then 1
        else 0
    end as player_exists
from (
    select 1 club_id
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
) c
```

Answer (score 0):

your query is perfect - just use its result to receive result you desire:

```
select
    club_id,
    decode(num_of_players, 0, 0, 1) as having_record
    from
    (select club_id
     ,  count(club_id) as num_of_players 
  from player 
 where club_id in (1,2,3,4) 
 group 
    by club_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

A `CASE` which uses the `COUNT` result:

```
select club_id,
  case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end having_record
from player
where club_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by club_id;
```

---

I don't have your tables, so - an example based on Scott's sample schema. In there, there are EMP and DEPT tables. Department 40 doesn't have any employees:

```
SQL>   SELECT d.deptno, COUNT (e.empno)
  2      FROM dept d LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  GROUP BY d.deptno
  4  ORDER BY d.deptno;

    DEPTNO COUNT(E.EMPNO)
---------- --------------
        10              3
        20              5
        30              6
        40              0         --> 0 employees

SQL>
```

So:

```
SQL>   SELECT d.deptno,
  2           CASE WHEN COUNT (e.empno) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END having_record
  3      FROM dept d LEFT JOIN emp e ON e.deptno = d.deptno
  4  GROUP BY d.deptno
  5  ORDER BY d.deptno;

    DEPTNO HAVING_RECORD
---------- -------------
        10             1
        20             1
        30             1
        40             0        --> no records here

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

try it

```
   select club_id, case when  count(club_id)>0 then 1 else 0 end as num_of_players from player 
   where club_id in (1,2,3,4) group by club_id
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have `club_id`, then presumably you have a table called `clubs`.  With such a table, I would recommend using `exist` as in:

```
select c.club_id,
       (case when exists (select 1 from player p where p.club_id = c.club_id)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as any_players
from clubs c
where c.club_id in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I recommend `EXISTS` over aggregation for performance reasons.  Aggregation requires counting *all* matching rows.  `EXISTS` can just stop at the first match.